# unix nohup sqlplus not working

Tags: unix, nohup

Trying to run all of the sql scripts in one NOHUP command. Below is my code. But, it is not running in nohup mode based on the below.  There are no errors either.  How do I run all of the below in one NOHUP command??

```
nohup sqlplus -S /NOLOG << %EOF% > engine_error.log
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT 1;
@$Level2/passFile server05
@engine_check.sql $stroke1 $bore1 
@engine_start.sql 
%EOF% &
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a script that must start some background jobs, make a script that starts functions with `&` and `nohup` your script.
When your script `startit.sh` looks like

```
function f1 {
   echo "f1 start"
   sleep 2
   echo "f1 end"
}

function f2 {
   echo "f2 start"
   sleep 1
   echo "f2 end"
}

function f3 {
   echo "f3 start"
   sleep 1
   cat <<END
f3 start here
more f3
f3 end here
END
   echo "f3 end"
}

f1 &
f2
f3 &
```

call `nohup startit.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in a script and then nohup the script. The nohup is probably getting confused because of the command.

```
#!/usr/bin/env 
#query.sh
sqlplus -S /NOLOG << %EOF% > engine_error.log
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT 1;
@$Level2/passFile server05
@engine_check.sql $stroke1 $bore1 
@engine_start.sql 
EOF
```

Then in your shell try doing this

```
nohup query.sh &
```

Comment: This is already inside of a script. Other parts of the script are running nohup as well.  Can you give me an example?

Comment: provided the example

Answer (score 0):

Problem is "&" (or any sign) in same line with EndOfMessage-String.

"EOF &" is not equal to "EOF" -> "inline script" is still waiting for "EOF".
A line with only the defined string after "<<" can finalize the "inline script":